# How can I get the cookies set by "Set-Cookie" in a HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httprequest, httpresponse, httpwebresponse

I was hoping the following code would yield a non-zero value:

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(loginUrl);
var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(webResponse.Cookies.Count);
```

yet no cookies seem to show up in `webRespone.Cookies`. I'm positive the cookies are there, as I'm sniffing the data with Fiddler. This is the response I'm getting:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: __Abc=Def; path=/; HttpOnly
PS-ResponseTime: 00:00:00.0624001
PS-Build: 2013-03-19-11-36-59
PS-Node: 02
Date: Tue, 19 Mar 2013 21:14:51 GMT
Content-Length: 57872
```

Does it have anything to do with the fact the cookie is `HttpOnly`?

### Edit

It's seems I can get them through `HttpWebRequest`'s `CookieContainer` which is certainly useful if I intend to proceed to a sequence of requests/responses. But why can't I access them the same through the `HttpWebResponse.Cookies` field, anyway?

Thanks

Comment: how did you get the Set-Cookie: __Abc=Def; path=/; HttpOnly in the http response?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you'll need to hand the request an instance of CookieContainer and then reference that instance to see the cookies.  Basically, HttpWebResponse does not directly expose cookies on the response that are marked as HttpOnly.